# solidity code warning in remix IDE

Tags: solidity, remix, ether, myetherwallet, bitcoin

I am trying to create a smart contract using the but it is showing warning message in a string

"Warning: Unused function parameter. Remove or comment out the variable name to silence this warning.
        uint256 initialSupply,
"

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The warning means what it says.

Your constructor baits the sender with three input arguments (34-36) and the sender might think those things are used.

At 38, 40 and 41 you hard code. The variables aren't used for anything. This could indicate a coding error, so the compiler is trying to warn you.

Why not say `name = tokenName;` instead?

Why not say `totalSupply = initialSupply * 10 ...`?

It would see that you're using the input for something and stop warning about a possible oversight.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I have removed the undefined variables but ABI encode format is not updating in the  input details